# ZeroMQ ROUTER strange received identities

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

Based on Python ZeroMQ, I am using a **`DEALER`** to **`ROUTER`** connection in order to implement a service broker ( a Majordomo pattern ).

I found that on certain scenarios the `ROUTER` starts getting messages which are all good except that their identity is not as expected, the received identity is one byte size and seem to be like an increasing integer.

To clarify I have a single `ROUTER` connected to multiple `DEALER`s, each `DEALER` has unique identity, e.g. `worker-x1y3z`, but at some point the `ROUTER` starts receiving these incrementing single byte identities e.g. `<`, then `=`, then `>` etc, and it keeps like that till the `ROUTER` is terminated, the rest of the message seems to be intact.

Any idea what can cause that?

Comment: And where is the MCVE-code, that replicates your indicated problem behaviour? This is a mandatory StackOverflow policy, so better revise and complete the MCVE in your original post.

Comment: `libzmq` issue? check [issue] (https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/842) (https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1537)